# Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration (API Abuse, Structural) in C#

Tags: c#, fortify

```
**Getting the below HP fortify issue: 

Mass Assignment:
Insecure Binder Configuration
(API Abuse, Structural)**
```

```
public class SampleModel
    {
        private SampleType sampleType;
        private SampleMode sampleMode;
    
    
        [JsonProperty("SampleType")]
        public SampleType SampleType
        {
            get { return sampleType; }
            set { sampleType= value; }
        }
    
        [JsonProperty("SampleMode")]
        public Mode Mode
        {
            get { return sampleMode; }
            set { sampleMode= value; }
        }
    
        public SampleModel(SampleType sampleType,
            SampleMode sampleMode)
        {
            this.sampleType= sampleType;
            this.sampleMode= sampleMode;
        }
    }
```

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum SampleType
    {

        today= 1,

        tomorrow= 2,
    }

 [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum SampleMode
    {

        Jan= 1,

        Feb= 2,
    }
```

**REST API POST call HANDLER:
Getting the issue in sampleNotification param here.**

```
    [Route()] 
    public object Post([FromBody] SampleModel sampleNotification) 
    {
        object response = HandleRemoteNotification(sampleNotification); 
        return response;
    }
```

**ANY help, thanks in advance**

Below issue I am getting in HP fortify.

When using frameworks that provide automatic model binding capabilities, it is a best practice to control which attributes will be bound to the model object so that even if attackers are able to identify other non-exposed attributes of the model or nested classes, they will not be able to bind arbitrary values from HTTP request parameters.

The framework binder used for binding the HTTP request parameters to the model class has not been explicitly configured to allow, or disallow, certain attributes.

Comment: Which architecture are you using? winforms? asp.net? wpf?